# What is the easiest way to install additional packages when using texlive from the Fedora repos?

Tags: packages, installing, repositories

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install an individual package on a Linux system?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016/how-do-i-install-an-individual-package-on-a-linux-system)

I stumbled upon a question here which recommends using tlmgr for conveniently installing additional packages. The Internet says that [you can't use tlmgr](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http://www.golatex.de/gibt-es-tlmgr-nicht-unter-opensuse-t4619.html&ei=GEVYUOHtLKj_4QTBmICQAg&usg=AFQjCNE1RuXongorPBu0L1cDqqTMfoVqGQ) if you installed texlive through rpm (that's how I installed mine).

Is there a way to get individual TeX packages easily, or do I have to manually copy them all into the folder structure?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016/how-do-i-install-an-individual-package-on-a-linux-system#question (just added, but hopefully 'the general case' here)

Comment: @JosephWright I didn't know that there are so few methods, I hoped there is something specific to replace tlmgr for Fedora, or maybe a third-party repo which has rpm packages not found in the official one. Thank you for the info, flagged as dupe.

Comment: There are a lot of TeX packages out there, so the effort would be considerable. People who want the fine-grain control that `tlmgr` offers usually just install 'vanilla' TL, then can update, _etc._ themselves. People who don't want to do that usually are happy to take what their Linux package manager offers.

Comment: I see. I just didn't know better when I installed the package manager version.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan on using fresh/updated TeXLive packages, you should consider installing TeXLive using the official installer, not software packages. As much as I like installing things with packages, I know of no other way to keep your installation up-to-date.

Comment: This might have its advantages, but it's not going to happen until my next OS reinstall, I don't have the time to deal with such a reinstallation. So, the question is what to do in the meantime.

Comment: It's not a reinstallation. You can install it to `/usr/local/texlive` or anywhere else. Once you set up your path, it will just override the existing packaged installation.